# FirebaseAuth - Replication of a modifed user login/email

Tags: java, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

Changing the email address of the currently logged in user works just fine using the `updateEmail` method of the user object, however it appears as if that change is not replicated to other logins, which still keep the previous email address.

Is there any notification I need to subscribe to / catch in order to be notified by such a change or is there another way to accomplish that?

Comment: What is **other logins**?

Comment: @excitedmicrobe For example other devices where the same user is logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Me, as a long time Firebaser, I read the docs a lot, like a lot. And I do have a workaround for this since there aren’t any built in.

First, if you provide multiple sessions per user, you’d want to use the `reauthenticate` method.

> Re-authenticate a user
>
> Some security-sensitive actions—such as deleting an account, setting a
>   primary email address, and changing a password—require that the user
>   has recently signed in. If you perform one of these actions, and the
>   user signed in too long ago, the action fails with the
>   FIRAuthErrorCodeCredentialTooOld error. When this happens,
>   re-authenticate the user by getting new sign-in credentials from the
>   user and passing the credentials to reauthenticate. For example:

```
let user = Auth.auth().currentUser
var credential: AuthCredential

// Prompt the user to re-provide their sign-in credentials

user?.reauthenticate(with: credential) { error in
  if let error = error {
// An error happened.
  } else {
// User re-authenticated.
  }
}
```

Using this, you’d get the error 90% percent of the time because of old credentials.

Or:

(1) On the change process. Set a specific key for the user on your real-time database or Firestore, 
(2) Check for that specific key on your app, if existed. That means the user needs to be re authenticated. Firebase will update the user credential on every new login.

I hope it helps. 
Here’s the docs:

[Manage users on Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/manage-users#delete_a_user)

Comment: Thanks a lot! I do already use `reauthenticate` when I update the email and password, however the problem is a changed email does not make it to active sessions on other devices. What you seem to suggest is to set a flag via the database to forcibly log out other sessions. Is that correct? So I assume there is no way to sync that change to the other devices, right?

Comment: @user10748160 Forcing a user to do specific app actions is never good, maybe; I suggest something like “please login with your new email” though. This is a problem with the caching system. It wouldn’t be a problem on your end. If you have saved the user email and username in the database, you could update it there, it wouldn’t be a problem. Since the email is already changed on googles servers. It just needs time to reflect

Comment: Thanks, I was specifically referring to an inbuilt solution of FirebaseAuth though. That does not exist, right? One has to use another mechanism, such as Firestore, to replicate that change?!

Comment: Anything just to tell your app regarding this account modification is fine, though. There isn’t any solution built in. Just the cache system. It’s updated on the servers. Don’t worry